# kotlin setter infinite recursion

Tags: android, kotlin

I am testing out kotlin on Android and ran into a problem where the setters of two variables get called in an infinite recursion because they try to change each other when they are originally set.

Here is a sample code

```
class Example {
    var a: Int = 0
        set(value) {
            b = a+10
        }

    var b:Int = 0
        set(value) {
            a = b-10
        }
}
```

And say I then use the following code:

```
val example = Example()
example.a = 10
```

It ends up causing an infinte recursions and eventually a stackoverflow. The setter for `b` calls the setter for `a` which in turn calls the setter for `b` again. And it goes on for ever.

I want to be able to update the value for `b` whenever `a` is set, but also update the value of `a` whenever `b` is set.

Any thoughts from the Kotlin experts out there? Would I need to make Java like setters in this case so that my setter code doesn't get called whenever I assign a value to `a` or `b`. Or is there some nifty Kotlin goodness that I can use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this example, you could only compute one of the properties, e.g.

```
var a: Int = 0

var b: Int
    get() = 10 - a
    set(value) { a = 10 - value }
```

In general, though, Kotlin doesn't provide access to the backing fields of other properties. You'll have to write it manually, e.g.

```
private var _a: Int = 0
var a: Int
    get() = _a
    set(value) {
        _a = value
        _b = 10 - value
    }

private var _b: Int = 10
var b: Int
    get() = _b
    set(value) {
        _b = value
        _a = 10 - value
    }
```

Kotlin won't generate its own backing fields for these properties because they are never used.